# Ms Access to PostreSQL does not show attachments & Vice Versa

Tags: postgresql, ms-access-2016, postgresql-9.6

I need to be Updating my PostgreSQL using the access interface. When I create a linked table in access from PostgreSQl, all  other columns show and can be updated well except the attachment field which I created as OID datatype in PostgreSQL.

I also tried exporting an Access table with attachments to PostgreSQL, the same happened, attachments did not show in PostgreSQL

Comment: An OID column is an auto-incrementing integer value in PostgreSQL which is hidden by default, which I imagine is why you wouldn't see it in MS Access. But an OID, as far as I know doesn't have anything to do with "attachments", so I'm puzzled why you would use that type of column in the first place?

Comment: @user9601310 I believe Ronald Muchini is asking about [Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html). They are referred to by their `oid`.  Ronald Muchini is that the case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver @user9601310 yes that is my case. I want to include Large objects in the postgreSQL tables and be able to update the table from Ms Access

Comment: Have you checked the ODBC Datasource settings for an "OID Options - Show Column" checkbox? Is it turned on?

Comment: Yes. Initially it was off but the problem persists even after turning on the check box and reconnecting.